# how to add a condition in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html table

```
<table>
            <tbody>
               <tr class="unread" ng-repeat="CU in InboxList">
                <td class="text-right mail-date">{{CU.time}}</td>
                </tr>

            <tr class="read">  
         <td class="text-right mail-date">12:00 pm</td>
                </tr>                      
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

here in my html table there are two tr class one is `tr class="read"` and other is `class="unread"` I have already binded `tr class="unread"`.now I want to check a condition if `{{cu.isread=0}}` then `tr` class read will bind otherwise `tr` class unread will `bind.how` to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with **[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

Example:

```
ng-class="(cu.isread === 0)  ? 'unread' : 'read'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<tr ng-class="{'read' : cu.isread === 0, 'unread': cu.isread !== 0}">...</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
       <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr data-ng-class="{unread: cu.isread == 0, read: cu.isread !=0}" ng-repeat="CU in InboxList">
                <td class="text-right mail-date">{{CU.time}}</td>
                </tr>

            <tr class="read">  
         <td class="text-right mail-date">12:00 pm</td>
                </tr>                      
            </tbody>
        </table>
```